# iText - How to replace a character with a dynamic checkbox in a pdf

Tags: pdf, checkbox, replace, itext, acrofields

I'm using iText to working on pdf documents.
I have a pdf document with non-dynamic checkboxes (they are made with the character "□", unicode \u25A1); I need to replace that checkboxes with the dynamic checkboxes of iText.
It's possible? 
I need it because the pdf document that I receive is not made by me and it contains that character.
Thanks for the help, and sorry for my not-perfect english

Comment: Try text extraction with a custom strategy to locate the checkboxes. Then either use the iText xtra cleanup classes to remove them or simply cover them in white. Then create a checkbox form fields right there.

Comment: Hi, I have located the checboxes and get their coordinates.
I have to put the checkboxes at that coordinates, but I can't.
How I can put the checkboxes in my document at that position?